# What is the solution

Tags: java, android

How can I save the number entered from EditText By user within a variable
Use this variable in other codes
For example, the user enters a weight. I want to save the value entered in a variable and use the variable in an equation and I do not want the page that asks for the values to appear after being entered by the user
If the user enters the required values, the page should not be displayed again when the application is running

this is my code in xml and i would to save the value in variables in java to use it in equation

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/weight" android:hint=" الوزن:" android:inputType="number"/> <EditText android:id="@+id/high" android:hint="الطول:" android:inputType="number"/> <EditText android:id="@+id/age" android:hint=" العمر:" android:inputType="number"/> <EditText android:id="@+id/sex" android:hint=" الجنس:" android:inputType="number"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your activity you can declare a "public static", for instance, you have Activity1.class

```
public class Activity1
{
     public static int weight;
}
```

When the user enters in the EditText you put a value in that attribute, then in another activity you can do:

```
Activity1.weight
```

You have to take into account 2 things:

1. Your activity where you gonna declare the public static attribute cannot be closed or deleted by another activity, also this must be in your main activity so you can be sure that you will always have access to that variable
2. If the app is closed and you have to start again the application this variable will be deleted, this means that the user has to specify the value always that the app starts

Comment: this is my code in xml and i would to save the value in variables in java to use it in equation

Comment: <EditText
            android:id="@+id/weight"
            android:hint=" الوزن:"
            android:inputType="number"/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/high"
            android:hint="الطول:"
            android:inputType="number"/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/age"
            android:hint=" العمر:"
            android:inputType="number"/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/sex"
            android:hint=" الجنس:"
            android:inputType="number"/>

Comment: What is the question, then? You just have to take the value of the EditText with id "weight" and save it in the variable that I just mentioned.